# How to do bulk insert from text file into sql table

Tags: csv, bulkinsert

I saw a few examples here, but I could not find the right solution.

I have a `.txt` file with a comma separated data that looks like this:

[image]

I have the following logic to `bulk insert` it into the table:

```
SET @cmd = 'BULK INSERT dbo.vw_RPT_TBL_Bulk_Staging FROM '''+ @FullFilePath +
            '''WITH(FIRSTROW = 1,FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'',TABLOCK)' 
EXEC (@cmd)
```

This is the table structure:

[image].

After the execution, everything is in one row.

I need to insert everything from the file into the table, so each line from the file will be on a separate row.
Later on I will need to extract the data and move it into different tables based on certain conditions.

How can I correctly insert the data?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your `ROWTERMINATOR` set incorrectly. Try this:

```
SET @cmd = 'BULK INSERT dbo.vw_RPT_TBL_Bulk_Staging FROM '''+ @FullFilePath +
            '''WITH(FIRSTROW = 1,FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',ROWTERMINATOR=''\r\n'',TABLOCK)' 
EXEC (@cmd)
```

Comment: Nope, did not work. Does it make sense to define columns for the staging table?

Comment: You're getting everything in a single row because SQL never runs into the  `ROWTERMINATOR`. I'd open up the source file with a hex editor to figure out what character is being used to signal the end of the row.

Comment: I have just LF at the end of the line

Comment: Try it with just `\r` as the `ROWTERMINATOR`. If that doesn't work, you'll probably need to convert the file to Windows format.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing to ROWTERMINATOR=''0x0a''